# Failed to connect to any address from IP finder

Tags: java, ignite

I am new to **Apache Ignite** and trying to run **Java** client for the Apache Ignite cluster (**GridGain 6.7.12**) 
Here is my cluster configurations running on three **Windows Server 2019** nodes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
            <property name="addresses">
              <list>              
                <value>HOST1</value>
                <value>HOST2</value>
                <value>HOST3</value>
              </list>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
        <!-- Set the cache name. -->
        <property name="name" value="MyCache"/>
        <!-- Set the cache mode. -->
        <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
        <!-- Other cache parameters. -->
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my client side **Java** code:

```java
CacheConfiguration<Integer, Person1> ccfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
ccfg.setName("PersonCache");
ccfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.TEN_MINUTES));
ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
// Registering indexed type.
ccfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Person1.class);

try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_MY_XML_CONFIGURATION")) {
    ignite.configuration().setClientMode(true);
    ignite.addCacheConfiguration(ccfg);
}
```

When I run my class, I get the following error:

> Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (make sure IP finder
>   addresses are correct and firewalls are disabled on all host
>   machines): [HOST1/192.168.30.05:47503,
>   HOST2/192.168.30.06:47503, HOST3/192.168.30.07:47503]

Here is a log from my client side code that I run from intelliJ:

```
[10:10:38]    __________  ________________ 
[10:10:38]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[10:10:38]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[10:10:38] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
[10:10:38] 
[10:10:38] ver. 8.7.12#20200211-sha1:e7932313
[10:10:38] 2020 Copyright(C) GridGain Systems, Inc. and Contributors
[10:10:38] 
[10:10:38] Ignite documentation: http://gridgain.com
[10:10:38] 
[10:10:38] Quiet mode.
[10:10:38]   ^-- Logging to file 'C:\Work\Java\GridGain\gridgain-community-8.7.12\work\log\ignite-8bc601d1.log'
[10:10:38]   ^-- Logging by 'Log4JLogger [quiet=true, config=/C:/Work/Java/GridGain/gridgain-community-8.7.12/config/ignite-log4j.xml]'
[10:10:38]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[10:10:38] 
[10:10:38] OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
[10:10:38] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_191-b12 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.191-b12
[10:10:38] Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
[10:10:38] Initial heap size is 256MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
[10:10:38] Configured plugins:
[10:10:38]   ^-- ml-inference-plugin 1.0.0
[10:10:38]   ^-- Copyright 2019 GridGain Systems, Inc. and Contributors.
[10:10:38] 
[10:10:38] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
[10:10:39] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[10:10:39] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[2020-02-26 10:10:53,772][ERROR][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#24][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=42, bytesSent=18, bytesRcvd0=42, bytesSent0=18, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1582733452265, hashCode=270755575, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#24]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.AtomicLongMetric@69a257d1, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/192.168.31.110:47101, rmtAddr=/192.168.30.5:55160, createTime=1582733452265, closeTime=0, bytesSent=18, bytesRcvd=42, bytesSent0=18, bytesRcvd0=42, sndSchedTime=1582733452265, lastSndTime=1582733452265, lastRcvTime=1582733452265, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioTracerFilter [tracer=GridProcessorAdapter []], GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@f70a112, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1332)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2472)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2239)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1880)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-02-26 10:10:54,780][ERROR][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#25][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=42, bytesSent=18, bytesRcvd0=42, bytesSent0=18, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1582733452776, hashCode=1994088511, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#25]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.AtomicLongMetric@69a257d1, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/192.168.31.110:47101, rmtAddr=/192.168.30.5:55162, createTime=1582733452776, closeTime=0, bytesSent=18, bytesRcvd=42, bytesSent0=18, bytesRcvd0=42, sndSchedTime=1582733452776, lastSndTime=1582733452776, lastRcvTime=1582733452776, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioTracerFilter [tracer=GridProcessorAdapter []], GridNioCodecFilter [parser=o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridDirectParser@f70a112, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1332)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2472)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2239)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1880)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[10:10:55] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
[10:10:55] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
[10:10:55]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
[10:10:55]   ^-- Specify JVM heap max size (add '-Xmx<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[10:10:55]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[10:10:55]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
[10:10:55] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
[10:10:55] 
[10:10:55] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[10:10:55] 
[10:10:55] Ignite node started OK (id=8bc601d1)
[10:10:55] Topology snapshot [ver=55, locNode=8bc601d1, servers=3, clients=2, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=14, offheap=4.8GB, heap=7.5GB]
```

Here is log from one of my server nodes:

```
[10:10:47,368][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#38][GridDiscoveryManager] Local java version is different from remote [loc=11, rmt=8]
[10:10:47,369][INFO][disco-event-worker-#38][GridDiscoveryManager] Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, consistentId=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 192.168.31.110, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=55, intOrder=30, lastExchangeTime=1582733447345, loc=false, ver=8.7.12#20200211-sha1:e7932313, isClient=true]
[10:10:47,370][INFO][disco-event-worker-#38][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=55, locNode=3f133d52, servers=3, clients=2, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=14, offheap=4.8GB, heap=7.5GB]
[10:10:47,374][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], crd=true, evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
[10:10:47,375][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
[10:10:47,375][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Completed partition exchange [localNode=3f133d52-f007-461b-9e95-0365b2ae12dd, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, consistentId=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 192.168.31.110, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=55, intOrder=30, lastExchangeTime=1582733447345, loc=false, ver=8.7.12#20200211-sha1:e7932313, isClient=true], done=true, newCrdFut=null], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0]]
[10:10:47,375][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Exchange timings [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], stage="Waiting in exchange queue" (3 ms), stage="Exchange parameters initialization" (0 ms), stage="Determine exchange type" (0 ms), stage="Exchange done" (0 ms), stage="Total time" (3 ms)]
[10:10:47,375][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Exchange longest local stages [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0]]
[10:10:47,376][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
[10:10:47,377][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], force=false, evt=NODE_JOINED, node=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8]
[10:10:55,254][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#25][TcpCommunicationSpi] Established outgoing communication connection [locAddr=/192.168.30.05:55163, rmtAddr=workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:47101]
[10:10:55,255][INFO][rest-#65][TcpCommunicationSpi] TCP client created [client=GridTcpNioCommunicationClient [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=766677, bytesSent=234131, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1582733455246, hashCode=1421332065, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#25]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=32768 cap=32768], inRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=0, sentCnt=0, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, consistentId=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 192.168.31.110, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=55, intOrder=30, lastExchangeTime=1582733447345, loc=false, ver=8.7.12#20200211-sha1:e7932313, isClient=true], connected=false, connectCnt=3, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=3, pairedConnections=false], outRecovery=GridNioRecoveryDescriptor [acked=0, resendCnt=0, rcvCnt=0, sentCnt=0, reserved=true, lastAck=0, nodeLeft=false, node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, consistentId=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 192.168.31.110, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=55, intOrder=30, lastExchangeTime=1582733447345, loc=false, ver=8.7.12#20200211-sha1:e7932313, isClient=true], connected=false, connectCnt=3, queueLimit=4096, reserveCnt=3, pairedConnections=false], outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.metric.impl.AtomicLongMetric@69a257d1, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/192.168.30.05:55163, rmtAddr=workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:47101, createTime=1582733455246, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1582733455246, lastSndTime=1582733455246, lastRcvTime=1582733455246, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioTracerFilter [tracer=GridProcessorAdapter []], GridNioCodecFilter [parser=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridDirectParser@16028c5a, directMode=true], GridConnectionBytesVerifyFilter], accepted=false, markedForClose=false]], super=GridAbstractCommunicationClient [lastUsed=1582733455246, closed=false, connIdx=0]], duration=3030ms]
[10:10:55,315][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-2-#26][TcpCommunicationSpi] Established outgoing communication connection [locAddr=/192.168.30.05:55165, rmtAddr=workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:47101]
[10:10:55,746][INFO][sys-#7681][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Fast replied to single message [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=55, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=null, nodeId=8bc601d1, evt=NODE_JOINED], nodeId=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8]
[10:10:56,189][INFO][disco-event-worker-#38][GridDiscoveryManager] Node left topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, consistentId=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 192.168.31.110, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=55, intOrder=30, lastExchangeTime=1582733447345, loc=false, ver=8.7.12#20200211-sha1:e7932313, isClient=true]
[10:10:56,190][INFO][disco-event-worker-#38][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=56, locNode=3f133d52, servers=3, clients=1, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=14, offheap=4.8GB, heap=4.0GB]
[10:10:56,192][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], crd=true, evt=NODE_LEFT, evtNode=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
[10:10:56,193][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
[10:10:56,193][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Completed partition exchange [localNode=3f133d52-f007-461b-9e95-0365b2ae12dd, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_LEFT, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, consistentId=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 192.168.31.110, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [workstation@domain.com/192.168.31.110:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=55, intOrder=30, lastExchangeTime=1582733447345, loc=false, ver=8.7.12#20200211-sha1:e7932313, isClient=true], done=true, newCrdFut=null], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0]]
[10:10:56,193][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Exchange timings [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], stage="Waiting in exchange queue" (1 ms), stage="Exchange parameters initialization" (0 ms), stage="Determine exchange type" (0 ms), stage="Exchange done" (0 ms), stage="Total time" (1 ms)]
[10:10:56,193][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Exchange longest local stages [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0]]
[10:10:56,193][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
[10:10:56,194][INFO][exchange-worker-#40][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=56, minorTopVer=0], force=false, evt=NODE_LEFT, node=8bc601d1-19a0-451f-a2d2-bacd56ca49d8]
```

From the client log, it looks like it is trying to connect only to the first server node even if I have three server nodes.
From the server log, I see that after exchange init, it took another 8 seconds to create a TCP client and start executing the instructions.

From the log, I see that it has correct IP address of all my three hosts.
Can someone please suggest solution to that? As I mentioned I am working in ALL WINDOWS environment.

Thanks

Comment: Why is the port strictly `47503`? I would expect a range here.

Comment: @alamar, as you can see in my XML configuration, i didn't specify ports so I think it picked from anywhere between 47500..47509

Comment: Your client should try all ports in range and not just a single one.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Please share your client code where you configure `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder`.

Comment: Vladimir Pligin, I am using same xml on server and client configuration as I listed above. When running in client mode, I am just setting ignite.configuration().setClientMode(true); in the code. Am I still missing something? I was reading that we can use same XML for the server and client for the Ignite

Comment: Please share log from one of server nodes.

Comment: alamar, I have added both client side logs and server side logs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specify a range of ports that can be used by Ignite clients/servers for discovery and communication needs. Check an XML snippet from this doc section:
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery#static-ip-finder

Double check that the IP finder config is the same for clients and servers. If the problem persists check there are no firewall rules enforced between servers and clients.

Comment: dmagda, I looked at the config you mentioned and made sure that I defined ports to go with the host (between 47500..47509). I also use same config for client and server. I also checked firewall rules. There are no firewall rules which restricts the communication between servers